# Android Change tabbar image and text programatically

Tags: android

I'm working on the android tab application, i want to change the tab bar content pragmatically, In my tab bar there is a `ImageView` and a `TextView` i need to change the `Imageview` image and the `TextView` text.

```
View tab = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1);
TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(android.R.id.orders_label);
```

this code didnt work either..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ImageView tabImage = (ImageView )tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.ordericon);
    TextView tabText = (TextView )tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.orders_label);
```

Comment: how u have define id to textview is textview and imageview defined in xml ?here is my xml where should i need to define textview and imageview in xml http://pastie.org/9664976

Answer (score 0):

You can change using below code

```
TextView title = (TextView )tabGroup.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.tv);
title.setText("Your text");
```